# "Run Code Analysis" does not run my code analyzer

Tags: visual-studio-2019, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, vspackage, visual-studio-package

I have written a code analyzer as part of my Visual Studio Package.

This corresponds to the instructions on [this page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix) except that it is part of my existing Package and not a stand-alone analyzer.

The analyzer registers itself to analyze the the SyntaxNode types StringLiteralExpression and InterpolatedStringExpression.

```
public override void Initialize ( AnalysisContext context )
{
  context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction ( AnalyzeString, SyntaxKind.StringLiteralExpression, SyntaxKind.InterpolatedStringExpression ) ;
}
```

As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/how-to-run-code-analysis-manually-for-managed-code?view=vs-2019)

> By default, live code analysis executes analyzers only for open files in Visual Studio.

This is correct. My analyzer runs on open files.

The same page continues:

> Run code analysis manually
>
> - In Solution Explorer, click the project.
> - On the Analyze menu, click Run Code Analysis on Project Name.
>
> Code analysis will start executing in the background. You should see the message 
>   **Running code analysis for ...** in the Visual Studio status bar towards 
>   the bottom-left corner. Once code analysis completes, the status message will
>   change to **Code analysis completed for** . Error list will soon refresh 
>   with all code analysis diagnostic

In this case, my analysis does not run.

I have placed breakpoints in the constructor, the SupportedDiagnostics property get, the Initialize function and the analyze function itself. None of them are entered if I start the code analysis manually via the Analysis menu (or via the context menu in the solution explorer).

Is there some additional condition required to activate a code analyzer for the manual code analysis?

Comment: I think this should be a bug filed here: http://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/new

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this weird issue.
In my case, I used the "wrong" Developer Command Prompt.
I installed VS Build tools after installing VS2017, which also installed the 2nd Developer Command Prompt.

The Start Menu shortcuts of the 2 Developer Command Prompt are as follows:

A: BuildTools (does not work!)

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

B. VS Professional (works!)

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

I spent all afternoon trying to figure this out! :-(